# trying to make an ad-hoc network between windows xp and windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, wireless-networking, ad-hoc-network

i'm using a usb modem on a windows xp 32 bit pro version and i'm trying to connect to this computer with a windows 7 64 bit pro version.

i made myself a personal ad-hoc wireless network. but it doesn't seem to work.

the windows xp computer wireless tray icon seems like it's connected

but when i go to the windows 7 computer it's seems connected with an error.

any help ? thanks in advance , udi

Comment: did it say something like "limited connectivity"? You need to enable internet sharing from the USB modem (and share it to the wireless network).

Comment: What is the error? Is the Windows 7 machine getting an IP address? Can you ping the computer that's connected to the modem? Do you have security enabled?

Answer (score 1):

i set up the network like the following link wrote down:

http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/using/networking/setup/adhoc.mspx

i'm using a lenovo laptop with a windows xp as my server for the ad-hoc network.

i have a zte usb modem and i allowed sharing on that connection.

when i try to connect to the ad-hoc network from my other computer (dell laptop with windows 7 64bit pro) it takes him about 2 minutes to connect and then it shows a yellow "!" mark on the wireless tray icon. and after a while it looks like its trying to reconnect or something like that (it shows the circle that moves around and search for networks).

in the main computer the internet is working and the wireless connection seems like it's working.